How to create a 2d swept circle along a wire?
For example, I have an edge created with gp_Circ2d/BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge2d and a wire created by BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge/BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire and I'd like to create a new wire (face, ultimately) which is the outline of the area covered by sweeping the shape along the wire. The sweep line may be a straight line, an arc or a bezier of some sort.
Any OpenCascade experts here who can help me out? I've just spent a while sifting through the documentation and examples but... can't find it (if it exists).

Are you trying to sweep a face along a wire ?
I have been trying to figure out how OpenCASCADE's swept solids works for the a couple days and I might have found something. Note that I am actually new to OpenCASCADE as well.
Here's the code :
        gp_Circ sweepCircle(gp_Ax2(gp_Pnt(0, 0, 0), gp_Dir(0, 0, 10)), 10);
        TopoDS_Wire sweepCircleWire = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(sweepCircle)).Wire();

        BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire wireBuilder;

        TColgp_Array1OfPnt pnts1(1, 3);
        pnts1.SetValue(1, gp_Pnt(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        pnts1.SetValue(2, gp_Pnt(300.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f));
        pnts1.SetValue(3, gp_Pnt(400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        Handle(Geom_BezierCurve) curve1 = new Geom_BezierCurve(pnts1);
        wireBuilder.Add(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(curve1).Edge());

        TColgp_Array1OfPnt pnts2(1, 3);
        pnts2.SetValue(1, pnts1.Last());
        pnts2.SetValue(2, gp_Pnt(700.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f));
        pnts2.SetValue(3, gp_Pnt(400.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f));

        Handle(Geom_BezierCurve) curve2 = new Geom_BezierCurve(pnts1);
        wireBuilder.Add(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(curve2).Edge());

        const TopoDS_Shape &sweptShape = BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe(wireBuilder.Wire(), BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(sweepCircleWire).Face());


Note that for the second bezier curve, the result is really weird. It may be a bug from OpenCASCADE itself or the way I use the library.
I apologize if I misread your question. I'm new to the whole CAD world and struggle to understand what people want to explain sometimes.

I went with adding a curve and then using BRepOffsetAPI_MakeOffset to turn it into a swept disc - works ok as long as the curve isn't too close to a full cirlce, so I detect that case and handle it differently.

@CharlieSkilbeck looks like a good work around. Do you have any exemple of the MakeOffset construction ?

Sure, I added the code in an answer

Thank you ! I'm not sure how to use it but I will try to implement it in my code

I went with adding a curve and then using BRepOffsetAPI_MakeOffset to turn it into a swept disc - works ok as long as the curve isn't too close to a full circle, so I detect that case and handle it differently.
gp_Ax3 up_axis3;
const gp_Pln &xy_plane = gp_Pln(up_axis3);

// make offset from wire(s) contained in a face
auto offset_wire = [&](TopoDS_Wire const &src_wire, Standard_Real radius) {
    BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace src_face(xy_plane);
    src_face.Add(src_wire);
    src_face.Build();

    BRepOffsetAPI_MakeOffset offset(src_face.Face(), GeomAbs_Arc);
    offset.Perform(radius);
    offset.Build();
    BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace face(xy_plane);
    for(TopExp_Explorer e(offset.Shape(), TopAbs_WIRE); e.More(); e.Next()) {
        face.Add(TopoDS::Wire(e.Current()));
    }
    face.Build();
    return TopoDS_Shape(face.Face());
};

